# CUDA Quantum code built with multiGPU support flag works as single with multiple GPU assigned

Tags: nvidia, multi-gpu, quantum-computing

I am evaluating CUDA Quantum; the goal is to build and run code with multi-GPU support
on an HPC system. I use CUDA Quantum via the official container image and using Nvidia `enroot` as container engine.

I build as follow with no errors:

```bash
nvq++ cuquantum_backends.cpp -o cuquantum_backends.x --qpu cuquantum --platform mqpu
```

as shown in the last GTC talk: "Inside CUDA Quantum" (https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/on-demand/session/gtcspring23-s51762/).

To get the number of available GPUs (each simulating a QPUs) I added the following (see https://nvidia.github.io/cuda-quantum/api/languages/cpp_api.html#platform)

```cpp
auto &platform = cudaq::get_platform();
printf("Num QPU %zu\n", platform.num_qpus())
```

Once executed the application prints

```bash
[ ... ]
Num QPU 1
```

while I am expecting

```bash
[ ... ]
Num QPU 2
```

As a check I ran `nvidia-smi` inside the container and both GPUs are seen.

I also built the code using the multi-gpu flag shown in the [official documentation](https://nvidia.github.io/cuda-quantum/using/simulators.html#cuquantum-multi-node-multi-gpu)

```bash
nvq++ cuquantum_backends.cpp -o cuquantum_backends.x --qpu cuquantum_mgmn
```

However that was not recognised by `nvq++`.

I see many possibilities for the code to behave in this way, among those are `enroot` and me missing something in how CUDA Quantum and cuQuantum work together, but I do not see a solution. Does anyone has any suggestion?

Thanks for helping

Marco

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the container image but my own build of [CUDA Quantum](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-quantum) (similar to this [build script](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-quantum/blob/main/scripts/build_cudaq.sh), with `CUQUANTUM_INSTALL_PREFIX` set accordingly)
worked as you'd have expected.

The build command that I used:

```
nvq++ cuquantum_backends.cpp -o cuquantum_backends.x --target nvidia --platform mqpu
```

I got the correct printout when executing the code, i.e.,

```
Num QPU 2
```

since my system has 2 GPUs.